# What does veterancy do to units?

Tags: steel-division-normandy-44

I understand that they'll have better morale, accuracy, etc, but does anyone have actual numbers on just how much they improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the a post in the following:

https://steamcommunity.com/app/572410/discussions/0/1333474229063766848/

For the Infantry Heavy Weapons (MGs, AT guns...etc) :

- 1 star : +15% RoF, -15% Received supression, +15% Resilience, +15% Mobility and +1 Accuracy.
- 2 stars : +30% RoF, -30% Received supression, +30% Resilience, +30% Mobility and +2 Accuracy.
- 3 stars : +45% RoF, -45% Received supression, +45% Resilience, +45% Mobility and +3 Accuracy.

For the Planes :

- 1 star : +1 to Accuracy, +1 at Dodging.
- 2 stars : +2 to Accuracy, +2 at Dodging.
- 3 stars : +3 to Accuracy, +3 at Dodging.

For the Infantry :

- 1 star : +15% to RoF, -15% Received supression, +15% Resilience.
- 2 stars : +30% to RoF, -30% Received supression, +30% Resilience.
- 3 stars : +45% to RoF, -45% Received supression, +45% Resilience.

For the Reco Infantry :

- 1 star : +15% to Optics, -15% Received Supression, +15% Resilience, +15% Mobility.
- 2 stars : +30% to Optics, -30% Received Supression, +30% Resilience, +30% Mobility.
- 3 stars : +45% to Optics, -45% Received Supression, +45% Resilience, +45% Mobility.

For the Reco Vehicles :

- 1 star : +15% to Optics, +15% Mobility, +1 Accuracy.
- 2 stars : +30% Optics, +15% Mobility, +2 at Dodging.
- 3 stars : +45% Optics, +45% Mobility, +3 at Dodging.

For the other Vehicles :

- 1 star : +15% to RoF, -15% Received Supression, +1 Accuracy.
- 2 stars : +30% to RoF, -30% Received Supression, +2 Accuracy.
- 3 stars : +45% to RoF, -45% Received Supression, +3 Accuracy.

Resilience and Dodging allows the units which benefit from these effects to either take less damage or increase the dispersion of the unit shooting them. In all cases, your unit will be less prone to take damages and thus really harder to kill.